# Joomla cannot save module

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Suddenly today in a development joomla 3.4.8 site I have can't save any module. Every time I change something in a module and then press save it return to module list without save the changes.I turn debug on and noticed that I have a duplicate query:

```
FROM 3k4mf_modules WHERE `client_id` = 0
```

This happens only when I assign the module in all pages. When I assign it to one or more pages manual the save works fine.

Note: This post is also published in joomla forums [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=708&t=903167) but without reply.

The logs I found in cpanel are empty. The logs of joomla only have this line:

```
2015-12-28T18:19:20+00:00   INFO 85.74.86.12    controller  Holding edit ID com_modules.edit.module.270 Array (     [0] => 270 )
```

Comment: Tell us more about your last changes, share us with your log file or give us list of installed modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.It was a javascript error which was solved by the theme creator. Some conflict with versions he told me.